# How to add polygons in JSON file?

Tags: qgis, r

From this GeoJSON file https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/fr/fr-all.geo.json, I would like to add some territories (called DOM) to the left of the map and Corsica (at the bottom of the map).
Do you know how I can modify this JSON file to add this territories with R or QGIS ?
I would not want to change the projection system and the extension because it suits me.
I manage to get the following map :

[image]

using this data.frame for the centroids (calculated from https://github.com/ddotta/SO_question/blob/main/dep_DOM.geojson) :

```
    X        Y code                 libelle reg
1    6.9908556 41.95822   2A            Corse-du-Sud  94
2    7.1913053 42.49171   2B             Haute-Corse  94
3    5.3483829 46.09992   01                     Ain  84
4    3.5579614 49.55944   02                   Aisne  32
5    3.1887240 46.39402   03                  Allier  84
6    6.2442408 44.10628   04 Alpes-de-Haute-Provence  93
7    6.2633394 44.66404   05            Hautes-Alpes  93
8    7.1166420 43.93691   06         Alpes-Maritimes  93
9    4.4250672 44.75251   07                 Ardèche  84
10   4.6411300 49.61557   08                Ardennes  44
11   1.5030642 42.92130   09                  Ariège  76
12   4.1616344 48.30421   10                    Aube  44
13   2.4141970 43.10391   11                    Aude  76
14   2.6790700 44.28027   12                 Aveyron  76
15   5.0864781 43.54595   13        Bouches-du-Rhône  93
16  -0.3623283 49.10048   14                Calvados  28
17   2.6695613 45.05128   15                  Cantal  84
18   0.2015060 45.71812   16                Charente  75
19  -0.6740966 45.78058   17       Charente-Maritime  75
20   2.4901053 47.06479   18                    Cher  24
21   1.8764959 45.35661   19                 Corrèze  75
22   4.7728608 47.42512   21               Côte-d'Or  27
23  -2.8639337 48.44118   22           Côtes-d'Armor  53
24   2.0194380 46.09038   23                  Creuse  75
25   0.7407319 45.10373   24                Dordogne  75
26   6.3618903 47.16582   25                   Doubs  27
27   5.1687456 44.68428   26                   Drôme  84
28   0.9955681 49.11410   27                    Eure  28
29   1.3708408 48.38800   28            Eure-et-Loir  24
30  -4.0594811 48.26139   29               Finistère  53
31   4.1802134 43.99350   30                    Gard  76
32   1.1733302 43.35927   31           Haute-Garonne  76
33   0.4533624 43.69249   32                    Gers  76
34  -0.5758413 44.82515   33                 Gironde  75
35   3.3679826 43.57903   34                 Hérault  76
36  -1.6390137 48.15451   35         Ille-et-Vilaine  53
37   1.5751850 46.77817   36                   Indre  24
38   0.6913230 47.25803   37          Indre-et-Loire  24
39   5.5763159 45.26319   38                   Isère  84
40   5.6977272 46.72812   39                    Jura  27
41  -0.7838053 43.96508   40                  Landes  75
42   1.4282767 47.61738   41            Loir-et-Cher  24
43   4.1654808 45.72691   42                   Loire  84
44   3.8068310 45.12783   43             Haute-Loire  84
45  -1.6779454 47.36304   44        Loire-Atlantique  52
46   2.3446499 47.91207   45                  Loiret  24
47   1.6050134 44.62353   46                     Lot  76
48   0.4605981 44.36697   47          Lot-et-Garonne  75
49   3.5000589 44.51638   48                  Lozère  76
50  -0.5591954 47.38891   49          Maine-et-Loire  52
51  -1.3265674 49.08029   50                  Manche  28
52   4.2389822 48.95001   51                   Marne  44
53   5.2275008 48.10917   52             Haute-Marne  44
54  -0.6578011 48.14666   53                 Mayenne  52
55   6.1649900 48.78761   54      Meurthe-et-Moselle  44
56   5.3815133 48.98926   55                   Meuse  44
57  -2.8096906 47.84693   56                Morbihan  53
58   6.6630526 49.03756   57                 Moselle  44
59   3.5044911 47.11573   58                  Nièvre  27
60   3.2202016 50.44744   59                    Nord  32
61   2.4242293 49.41013   60                    Oise  32
62   0.1296612 48.62379   61                    Orne  28
63   2.2900236 50.49324   62           Pas-de-Calais  32
64   3.1404568 45.72574   63             Puy-de-Dôme  84
65  -0.7614160 43.25674   64    Pyrénées-Atlantiques  75
66   0.1641597 43.05316   65         Hautes-Pyrénées  76
67   2.5224963 42.60076   66     Pyrénées-Orientales  76
68   7.5499858 48.67025   67                Bas-Rhin  44
69   7.2728888 47.85997   68               Haut-Rhin  44
70   4.6419432 45.87025   69                   Rhône  84
71   6.0866381 47.64136   70             Haute-Saône  27
72   4.5418367 46.64475   71          Saône-et-Loire  27
73   0.2211735 47.99435   72                  Sarthe  52
74   6.4433087 45.47774   73                  Savoie  84
75   6.4279657 46.03380   74            Haute-Savoie  84
76   2.3407305 48.85655   75                   Paris  11
77   1.0275769 49.65487   76          Seine-Maritime  28
78   2.9337584 48.62729   77          Seine-et-Marne  11
79   1.8416433 48.81608   78                Yvelines  11
80  -0.3181374 46.55540   79             Deux-Sèvres  75
81   2.2785227 49.95807   80                   Somme  32
82   2.1663091 43.78523   81                    Tarn  76
83   1.2814050 44.08600   82         Tarn-et-Garonne  76
84   6.2450096 43.44011   83                     Var  93
85   5.1771125 44.00757   84                Vaucluse  93
86  -1.2983798 46.67563   85                  Vendée  52
87   0.4591667 46.56422   86                  Vienne  75
88   1.2348542 45.89253   87            Haute-Vienne  75
89   6.3800894 48.19639   88                  Vosges  44
90   3.5645381 47.84020   89                   Yonne  27
91   6.9273309 47.63182   90   Territoire de Belfort  27
92   2.2434261 48.52302   91                 Essonne  11
93   2.2459084 48.84686   92          Hauts-de-Seine  11
94   2.4786925 48.91744   93       Seine-Saint-Denis  11
95   2.4679784 48.77776   94            Val-de-Marne  11
96   2.1325104 49.08215   95              Val-d'Oise  11
97  -3.9824014 46.59077  971              Guadeloupe  01
98  -3.2847659 42.35193  976                 Mayotte  06
99  -3.3469921 43.40534  974              La Réunion  04
100 -3.6056836 45.55131  972              Martinique  02
101 -3.5232007 44.45863  973                  Guyane  03
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I think the initial shape from code.highcharts is not accurate. The area is much smaller than the actual area of France and when plotting with mapview it is not properly located

```r
# Libraries

library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(mapview)
library(tmap)
library(giscoR)

# Original
tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".json")
download.file(
  "https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/fr/fr-all.geo.json",
  tmp
)



France_main <- st_read(tmp)
#> Reading layer `file3f0862a250d5' from data source 
#>   `C:\Users\diego\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUbhCil\file3f0862a250d5.json' 
#>   using driver `GeoJSON'
#> Simple feature collection with 19 features and 8 fields
#> Geometry type: GEOMETRY
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -999 ymin: -689 xmax: 9851 ymax: 9851
#> Projected CRS: RGF93 / Lambert-93
units::set_units(sum(st_area(France_main)), "km^2")
#> 52.28913 [km^2]

# Not right
tm_shape(France_main) +
  tm_polygons() +
  tm_graticules()
```

[image]

So I followed here an alternative approach. I used the shape you provided for extracting the location of the islands and added a proper shape of mainland France using giscoR package. I used the same projection of the initial shapefile.

```r
# New map

new <- st_read("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ddotta/SO_question/main/dep_DOM.geojson")
#> Reading layer `dep_DOM' from data source 
#>   `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ddotta/SO_question/main/dep_DOM.geojson' 
#>   using driver `GeoJSON'
#> Simple feature collection with 101 features and 3 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -5.138352 ymin: 41.46249 xmax: 8.228866 ymax: 51.089
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# Same CRS
new <- st_transform(new, st_crs(France_main))

units::set_units(sum(st_area(new)), "km^2")
#> 570298 [km^2]


qtm(new)
```

[image]

At this point, the only difference that I spotted with the first map is the subdivision levels. It seems that in the initial shapefile this is grouped by NUTS1 level, so I followed that on my example.

```r
# Select only relevant shapes and group Corse
DOM_COR <- new %>%
  filter(reg %in% c("94", "01", "02", "03", "04", "06")) %>%
  group_by(reg) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  select(-n)


qtm(DOM_COR)
```

[image]

Now we have only the islands and I have grouped also Corse in one single shape. Now I add the NUTS1 shapes of mainland France.

```r
# Add NUTS1 levels

FRA_NUTS1 <- gisco_get_nuts(country = "France", res = 3, nuts_level = 1, year = 2021) %>% 
st_transform(st_crs(DOM_COR))

# Exclude DOM and COR, we already have them
FRA_NUTS1_main <- FRA_NUTS1 %>% filter(!FID %in% c("FRM", "FRY"))

units::set_units(sum(st_area(FRA_NUTS1_main)), "km^2")
#> 539978.2 [km^2]

qtm(FRA_NUTS1_main)
```

[image]

So we have now mainland France. Now I just add the rows of the islands

```r
# Join rows and final map

FRA_final <- bind_rows(FRA_NUTS1_main, DOM_COR)
qtm(FRA_final)
```

[image]

As a last check, I write a geojson file and I reload it to verify that all was correct.

```r
# To geojson
st_write(FRA_final, "FRA.geojson")
#> Writing layer `FRA' to data source `FRA.geojson' using driver `GeoJSON'
#> Writing 18 features with 10 fields and geometry type Multi Polygon.

# Read
FRA_read <- st_read("FRA.geojson")
#> Reading layer `FRA' from data source 
#>   `C:\Users\diego\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKUbBAt\reprex-14f4686b3775-daft-loon\FRA.geojson' 
#>   using driver `GeoJSON'
#> Simple feature collection with 18 features and 10 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 99343.5 ymin: 6049647 xmax: 1082847 ymax: 7110522
#> Projected CRS: RGF93 / Lambert-93

qtm(FRA_read, fill = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Hope that this helps, regards

Comment: Waouh, many thanks for your answer !